# Formulario Html no envía variable tipo Double al controlador

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Estoy teniendo problemas al enviar un valor numérico del tipo Double a través de una vista utilizando BeginForm. Lo que pasa es que al enviar como valor un número entero, no hay ningún problema. Pero a la hora de enviar un numero con separador de decimales (utilizo el . en éste caso), el valor recibido en el controlador es siempre un 0.
Adjunto sector de modelo, vista y controlador.

Modelo, solo el sector que funciona mal.

```
public class LicenceRequestViewModel
{        
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "La cantidad de días es requerido")]
    public double DaysRequest { get; set; }
}
```

Vista, también extraje la parte necesaria:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LicenceRequest", "Licences", FormMethod.Post, new { 
@id = "requestLicenceForm", @class = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group" id="daysRequest">
           @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DaysRequest, "Días a solicitar", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-10" })
       <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DaysRequest, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @min = "1", @Type ="text"}})
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DaysRequest, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
       </div>
    </div>
}
```

Y finalmente el controlador, lo único que necesito es recibir el número con su decimal, que en el futuro siempre sera un 5 (pero eso no interesa ahora).

```
public ActionResult LicenceRequest(LicenceRequestViewModel viewModel, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{
//código no necesario.
}
```

El servidor en el cuál se aloja la página web es Azure, pero la aplicación no funciona tampoco de manera local. Espero que alguien pueda revisar ésto.

Muchas gracias. Saludos!

Comment: Si cambias la propiedad a string recibes el valor en el post del form ? que pasa si cambias a @Html.TextBoxFor() en lugar del EditorFor() ? por supuesto no necesitas indicar el type=text como atributo html

Comment: Hola. Al ser un código tan grande, utiliza el viewModel en muchas ocasiones, por ende decidí ver que podía hacer sin modificar eso. Por suerte, un compañero de trabajo me facilito parte de un código que había escrito anteriormente para solucionar dicho problema. Ahora lo agregare como solución. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente pude resolver el problema gracias a un compañero de trabajo que es más veterano en asp.net. Aquí dejo la solución.

El problema era entre culturas e idiomas. Para solucionarlo deben agregar éste código al comienzo de "Global.asax.cs" (Hasta por encima de Application_Start).

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        var currentCulture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
        currentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
        currentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
        currentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
            CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new
            CultureInfo("es-ES");

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = currentCulture;
    }
```

Y luego en el "Web.config", deben ubicar la línea de código que dice "Globalization" y dejarla de la siguiente forma, para que coincida con el "global.asax.cs".

```
<globalization uiCulture="es" culture="es-ES" />
```

En mi caso funciono a la perfección, yo utilizo como separador de decimales el ". (punto)". El servidor de mi página se encuentra en Brasil y actualmente trabajo en Argentina.